# Communication between back-end and remote AWS Instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, socket.io, rabbitmq

I'm currently working on a real-time application, and I have a few questions for my back-end architecture. This application basically allows you to render a 3D-Model into an image.

I have a React front-end that interacts with my Heroku-hosted server (Nodejs) using Socket.IO.

Now, recently I've had to handle more performance demanding tasks (running Blender on a remote server), so I've started using a bootable "on-demand" AWS EC2 Instance (g4.large).

My back-end sends a request to an API hosted on the EC2 instance, and it renders the image in a subprocess.

My issue is:
I want the informations received from the subprocess to be communicated to my heroku app (the progress made, time remaining...), then to the user through my sockets.

Here's a graph detailing the communication process in my app:
[image: Communication graph]

I thought about adding a message queue service such as RabbitMQ on the AWS app, and use my heroku app as a consumer, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to do it.

I could also implement a socket communication between the Heroku app and EC2 instance, but it seems overkill because the communication will be mostly one-sided (the instance sends information to the app).

Any ideas what's the best thing to do there ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of using a full blown RabbitMQ, have you considered using AWS SQS?

Comment: @stijndepestel Hey, thanks for your answer. I have not yet considered it, but I will look into it, thanks!

Comment: @KaiBurjack thanks for your answer. The main issue I'm seeing is that it may be confusing to use websockets twice on my Heroku app: once as the server, and once as a client, don't you think ?

Comment: why not just POST back the progress? (from aws to heroku)

Comment: @KaiBurjack you're absolutely right, thanks for your help!

Comment: @ITgoldman it would mean too many request, multiple request per seconds per process running.